# What was the first work with High-rise buildings on the Moon?

Tags: history-of, moon

Provided that on our Moon the gravitational forces are much smaller than on Earth and that the lateral forces (wind, moonquake) are negligible, it could be possible to construct buildings a few km high.

I'm aware that for many different reasons, some exposed in [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221742/high-rise-buildings-on-the-moon#comment605872_221742), such a construction is not a good idea.

In the past I read quit a lot of SF but I do not remember a single title mentioning the inherent advantages (from the structural engineering point of view) of high-rise buildings on the Moon, possibly because, as I've already mentioned, it's not a good idea for reasons not connected with structural engineering.

What was the first work where this high-rise building idea is developed?

Answer (score 3):

Murray Leinster’s 1957 *City on The Moon* gives several good details about the buildings in the city.

[image: City on The Moon front cover]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: It would be worthwhile editing in some quotes to back this up.

Comment: Have to wait a bit to get the copy.

Comment: "Civilian City was three dust-heaps, lying some forty-odd tortuous miles away through the mountains.  Moon-dust, piled untidily over inflated half-balloons, held those giant air bubbles safely confined--by its weight."  (City on the Moon)  Doesn't sound like high rises.

Comment: "A hundred and fifty men lived and worked and squabbled in the City.  In addition, there were spotter stations where radar marked the fall of the drone-rockets that brought supplies for the City from Earth.  Then there were the military missile bases, which were the first footholds of mankind on any natural celestial body that was not man-made.  Their positions were top secret.  And beyond farside of the moon, remote in emptiness, was the Space Laboratory."  (City on the Moon)  So the cover art is pure artistic license.

Comment: How tall were the buildings (missile silos)? The population isn’t the question. A gantry can be pretty tall

Comment: Leinster was a true visionary.  His story "A Logic Named Joe", written in 1946 predicted many aspects of the internet.

Comment: @VogonPoet A gantry isn't a building, though.  One of the descriptions of the interior of a dome describes privacy cubicles that don't even have ceilings, so it's not like there were multi-story buildings.  And I think a "high rise" needs to be at _least_ 3 stories tall.

Comment: Yeah not a very objective standard. I think a gantry fits the engineering requirements of the question, though not in the definition of “skyscraper.” Basically if anything was built tall taking advantage of the low gravity I feel it answers the problem.

Comment: Reading the comments it looks controversial if _City on The Moon_ describe high rise buildings, especially very high ones that take advantage of low gravity and no lateral forces.